# Can you Run Unit on method with a WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-workmanager

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a local unit test on method with a WorkManager. I've run a local unit test that connects to a method with a WorkManager and I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
```

I can run an Intrustemented unit test with a method that has a WorkManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WorkManager, you cannot run a local unit test on your host machine, you need to write an Integration Test that runs on the emulator or on an Android device.
There's documentation available on the [WorkaManager Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing-worker-impl) and this is also covered in a couple of codelabs:

- [Advanced WorkManager](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager/#5)
- [Use Kotlin Coroutines in your Android App](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#11)